# How do I execute the curl command in Shell Script with Jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins, curl

I want to execute the curl command in Shell Script with Jenkins.

Executing Shell Script alone from remote works very well.

However, running shell scripts through Jenkins will result in an infinite load as shown below.

Let me know how to fix it.

myShellScript

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "curl Start"
curl --request GET 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/server/someting/work'
echo "curl End"
```

================================================

my jenkins Execute shell script on remote host using ssh
[image]

==================================================
Jenkins Log Result

It's been like that for an hour, like the image below.
Connection logs do not exist in the URL.

[image]

And
ssh account@my-test-server "/home/account/folder/myShellScript.sh"

It worked well when I executed the command as above.

Please help me.